# MySQL Error: right syntax to use near ''

Tags: mysql, syntax

I have the this query:

```
 SELECT owner,
    CASE WHEN id IN (1,2,4) THEN 25
    ELSE 
    CASE WHEN owner = 25 THEN NULL 
    END as owner
    FROM board2
```

and get this error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as owner

    FROM board2' at line 9
```

What is my mistake?

Example:
id - owner - result owner
2 - 4 - 7 (id is selected and owner has changed
3 - 7 - 7 (id is selected and owner has changed
4 - 7 - NULL (id isnt selected, owner is the same like the new one, so owner is set to NULL
5 - 4 - 4 (id isnt selected, owner isnt the new owner, no changes

x = (2, 3) (The ids which have to changed)
y = 7 (The new owner)

Comment: Trying to understand but still not able to follow it.

Comment: in pseudocode:
$ids_which_should_change = (2,3);
foreach ($rows as $value)
{
      if ($value['id'] is in $ids_which_should_change)
            $value['owner']=$new_owner;
      else if ($value['owner'] == $new_owner)
            $value['owner']=NULL;
}

But if I implement it like this I need a lot of querys and thats slow... so I hoped, that one query could do the same

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is the logic you want (you have 2 CASEs, not 1 with different alternatives):
SELECT owner,
   CASE 
       WHEN id IN (1,2,4) THEN 25
   ELSE
   END
   CASE
       WHEN owner=25 THEN NULL
   ELSE 
   END
FROM board2

If not then you can't have the WHEN in the 2nd CASE and may want to go with IF, ELSEIF, ELSE, END IF.

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax issue in the `case-when` , in addition you are selecting `owner` 2 times which is also again an error

It should be something as

```
SELECT owner,
CASE 
WHEN id IN (1,2,4) THEN 25
WHEN owner = 25 THEN NULL 
else 'ABC' ---- better to provide else other wise non-matching data will be selected as null, give something as you want
END as `some_other_col_name` --- a different col name since owner is already selected on the top
FROM board2
```

Comment: Hm... It doesn't throw an error anymore. But its not working. It doesnt do anything :D

What I want the sql to do is:
If the id of the row is in the list x, then it shall set the owner to y. If not and the owner is already y it shall set the owner to NULL.
So:
id - owner
2 - 4
3 - 7
4 - 7
5 - 4

x = (2, 3)
y = 9

result:
id - owner
2 - 9
3 - 9
4 - NULL
5 - 4

I think, this sql cant be that complicated :/

Comment: Provide some sample data and expected result from that, since its hard to do guess and write a query.

Comment: Add an example in the top post